# How can i run node cli with ./index

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, command-line-interface

I am trying to make node cli
I want to run cli with ./index
My package.json
`

```
{
  "name": "cli",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "./index": "index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

`

i added ./index in bin but when trying to run ./index showing no such file or directory: ./index

But when trying to run only index its running i want to run with ./index

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs that npm provides (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#bin), this should be the way to set "bin":

```
{
  "name": "cli",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "index": "./index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```